# How do I make $(this) relevant inside a function called by live external id

Tags: jquery

I have a live function that triggers the 'openwindow' function and I need to also be able to call that 'openwindow' function seperately, hence my 'initial function call'. The problem is, the id #open-window featured in my live call is the id I want to be able to apply $(this) to (in the openwindow function). If anyone has any suggestions on how to make this possible, I would appreciate it.

```
function openwindow(user, token) {
if(user==''){
    var user = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var token = $('#token').attr('data-value');
}
//append some information

}

//event triggered on click
$('#open-window').live('click', openwindow);

//initial function call
openwindow('hey','hey');
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “however I don't think it applies to my live function”? What exactly is it that does not apply to the function bound via `live`?

Comment: bad choice of words...I edited it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact functionality you want.  But here is an attempt to modify what you had to use the event object that jQuery provides.  You can use this object to store your own data (as I show) and get the original dom object.

Some documentation here.
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

```
function openwindow(event) {
   inUser = event.data.user;
   inToken = event.data.token;

   if(inUser=='default'){
      var user = $(event.target).attr('data-name');
      var token = $('#token').attr('data-value');
   }
//append some information
}

//event triggered on click
$('#open-window').live('click', { user : 'default', token : 'default' }, openwindow);

//initial function call
openwindow({ data : { user : 'hey', token :'hey' },
             target : '#somelocation that has a data-name' });
```

Comment: @scarface - I had a dyslexic moment. The `'click'` should be before the user data. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Scarface - saw another problem... see edit.  Should not matter because inUser will always have a value, but just in case you want to change your default behavior you should remember there may be an expectation that `target` will have a value when you call from outside jQuery call back.

Comment: Well the initial function works still but the live function is not executing. In firebug it says F.apply is not a function in Jquery-1.3.2.min.js or which is my jquery file.

Comment: haha it works now buddy. Thanks Hogan. This time no problems. Nice troubleshooting!

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
$('#open-window').live('click', openwindow);

function openwindow(event, user, token) {
 if(user==''){
    var user = $(event.target).attr('data-name');
    var token = $('#token').attr('data-value');
 }
}
```

Comment: hah... I kept prompting people to write this answer and no one did, then I write it myself and see when I'm done you just posted it.

Comment: Naveed the live function does not work if the if statement is present, I alerted user and it is equal to #open-window...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use the same function for something that is completely different? A better approach would probably be to just seperate them out:

```
function openwindow(user, token) {
    // do some work...
}

//event triggered on click
$('#open-window').live('click', function(e) {
    openwindow($(this).attr('data-name'), $('#token').attr('data-value'));
});

//initial function call
openwindow('hey','hey');
```

Answer (score 0):

theres a apply method on all functions with allows you the chose what the this
context of the function is gonna be.

like

```
myFunction.apply(newThis, [arguments,in,a,array]);
```

this isn't really a good programing convention tho you should probably use an anonymous function in the live callback and call openWindow with the right arguments .

Comment: If you don’t have an array for the arguments, you could also use call: `myFunction.call(newThis, arguments, without, array);`